# FBSDKShareLinkContent PlaceID

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to add a share dialog where the location is pre-filled, however the location will not show.

Simply, the code I am using is:

```
 FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc]init];
 content.placeID=@"295425343918748";
 [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need "publish_actions" permission from Facebook to post location.

Please go through this once- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299779/how-to-post-location-with-image-to-facebook-in-ios/34714589#34714589)